# Can't animate FAB visible in M3 Scaffold

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to get behaviour where I can toggle visibility of a FAB, with a bit of entry/exit animation, in the Compose `Scaffold`.

#### The issue

The FAB disappears fine. However, whatever I try, I can't get it to reappear - it's like it totally disappears from the tree, never to return!

This code reproduces the issue:

```kotlin
class TestActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            var fabVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
            Scaffold(
                floatingActionButton = {
                    AnimatedVisibility(visible = fabVisible) {
                        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {
                            Icon(Icons.Default.Star, contentDescription = null)
                        }
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Button(onClick = { fabVisible = !fabVisible }) {
                    Text("Click to toggle FAB")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a demo - the FAB does a sort of wipe out, but then never returns:

[image]

#### Workarounds I've attempted

If I do any of the following, the FAB will toggle:

1. Put the FAB in another area, such as the `Scaffold` content or `topbar` area.
2. Remove the `AnimatedVisibility`.
3. Put the FAB inside an explicitly-sized `Box`:

   ```kotlin
   …
   Scaffold(
       floatingActionButton = {
           Box(
               modifier = Modifier
                   .width(56.0.dp)
                   .height(56.0.dp)
           ) {
               AnimatedVisibility(visible = fabVisible) {
                   FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {
                       Icon(Icons.Default.Star, contentDescription = null)
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   )
   …
   ```

Obviously solutions 1 and 2 don't achieve what I want, and solution 3 (the `Box` solution) isn't ideal - I have to know the size of the FAB to do this (I imagine there's probably a way to remember its intrinsic size when first visible?) and the animation is odd - it goes from the corner from the middle rather than from the centre, and the elevation suddenly 'pops' right at the end:

[image]

What should I do to get the FAB entering and exiting as expected?

Comment: Tried with material 2 and it worked. Can you add compose version and material 3 versions you are using?

Comment: The view appears from top right corner because of default parameters, you can override it with `AnimatedVisibility(visible = fabVisible, enter = fadeIn(), exit = fadeOut())`. As to rest of the issue, it looks like a bug, I suggest you [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1253476) it.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, It works for me if I change the animation to fade. (A bit weird animation, but works)

Answer (score 14):

Try with `scaleIn` and `scaleOut` animations.

```
 AnimatedVisibility(
      visible = fabVisible,
      enter = scaleIn(),
      exit = scaleOut(),
 ) {
      FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {
          Icon(Icons.Default.Star, contentDescription = null)
      }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently it's some sort of bug. It's supposed to be fixed. I'm having the same problem. The only thing that helped is to use the scaleIn/scaleOut animations. The default animations don't work at all for me (nothing gets shown), and the "fade" animations clip the FAB. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/224005027